# Atualizando MYSQL para MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

O que eu posso fazer para resolver isso? Dei uma pesquisada, mas não consegui entender oq estou fazendo de errado, meus conhecimentos são básicos no assunto. Comprei um aplicativo que veio MSQL antigo que não funcionava mais em PHP7, estou tentando atualizar.

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd1/664/11665664/public_html/news/api.php on line 23**

**Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd1/664/11665664/public_html/news/api.php on line 32**

**Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /storage/ssd1/664/11665664/public_html/news/api.php on line 55
[]**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "id11665664_admin";
    $username = "id11665664_lincoln";
    $password = "157abc";

    // Create connection

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check connection

    if (!$mysqli) {

        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
<?php

    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
    //mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
    {
            //$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category WHERE cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY tbl_news_category.cid DESC";     
            //$resouter = mysql_query($query);

            $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.nid DESC";         
            $resouter = mysqli_query($query);

    }
    else if(isset($_GET['latest_news']))
    {
            $limit=$_GET['latest_news'];        

            $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.nid DESC LIMIT $limit";            
            $resouter = mysqli_query($query);
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['apps_details']))
    { 
            $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_settings WHERE id='1'";       
            $resouter = mysqli_query($query);
    }
    else
    {   
            $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category ORDER BY cid DESC";         
            $resouter = mysqli_query($query);
    }

    $set = array();

    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($resouter);
    if($total_records >= 1){

      while ($link = mysqli_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $set['NewsApp'][] = $link;
      }
    }

     echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set)); 
?>
```

Comment: se é mysqli, corrija o titulo da sua pergunta

Comment: perdão, não reparei no erro de digitação

Comment: Tem alguns erros com seu código. Você mal abre a conexão com banco de dados e então a fecha. Todas as chamadas seguintes a `mysqli_close($mysqli);` darão erro. Quanto aos alertas, essa é a assinatura de `mysqli_query` [`mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] ) : mixed`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php), no primeiro parâmetro passe a referencia para a conexão com o BD que obteve com `mysqli_connect`. Como exemplo um de suas consultas ficaria assim: `$resouter = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);`

Answer (score -1):

Procure utilizar a conexão para realizar os processos, ou seja, armazene-a em uma variável para então ter gestão da execução...

```
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    try 
    {
        self::$connection = new mysqli($array[0]["server"],$array[0]["user"],$array[0]["pwd"],$array[0]["db"],$array[0]["port"]) or die('Erro ao conectar o banco');
        mysqli_set_charset(self::$connection, 'utf8');
        if (!self::$connection)
        {
            die('Conexao invalida');
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e ) 
    {
        echo "Excecao ao conectar o banco";
        exit;
    }
```

Veja que estou usando uma classe (self) mas nada que voce nao resolva com uma variavel
E ai, considerando que conectou...

```
self::$connection->query('Select * from table')
```

Comment: pode explicar como sua resposta resolve o problema de migração dito na pergunta, que já tem uma conexão no codigo?

Comment: Desculpa MrCunha, não entendi sua resposta

Comment: Lincoln, no exemplo que passei voce vai ver que utod no mysqli trabalha com 2 parametros, a conexao aberta e o parametro, ou seja: **$resouter = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);** pegando teu codigo como exemplo (veja que voce deve passar a variavel da conexao aberta e na sequencia a query), diferente da versao antiga que nao esperava mais de uma conexao